# Resolving overload ambiguity with null

Tags: f#

I'm working with an API in F# (that I have no control over) which declares two constructors like so:

```cs
public TheType(string bar, bool foo)

public TheType(IDisposable baz, bool foo)
```

I need to create an instance of the object using the first constructor, but passing `null` for bar. The F# compiler of course gets confused about which constructor I am trying to resolve:

```
//Private field
static let blah : TheType = new TheType(null, false)
```

I can resolve the issue by casting `null` to string:

```
static let blah : TheType = new TheType(null :> string, false)
```

Which works, but that gives me a compilation warning:

> The type 'string' does not have any proper subtypes and need not be used as the target of a static coercion

Which also makes sense. Is there a way to resolve the overload ambiguity without resorting to compilation warnings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the type of null:

```
static let blah : TheType = new TheType((null : string), false)
```